# Convert arrays of object to LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, java-stream

I would like to create a LinkedHashMap using Java Stream API.

```
Map<String, String> builtProps = Maps.newLinkedHashMap();
    Couple[] callLegData = getCallLegData();
    for (Couple cl : callLegData) {
        String key = cl.key;
        String value = cl.value;
        // building properties
        String buildProperty = deviceInfo.buildProperty(key);

        // call device info
        if (buildProperty != null) {
            builtProps.put(buildProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

I tried something like this

```
        Stream.of(callLegData)
        .map(k -> deviceInfo.buildProperty(k.key))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key, value -> value, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

But failing to get **value** from callLegData ie *callLegData.value*.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to first filter out the object for which the method `buildProperty` returns null and map the rest to a simple entry and collect to map as you already done it in your example:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;

....

Stream.of(callLegData)
      .filter(cld -> deviceInfo.buildProperty(cld.key) != null)
      .map(cld -> new SimpleEntry<>(deviceInfo.buildProperty(cld.key), cld.value))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

**EDIT**

If `buildProperty` is a heavy operation and you don't want to call that method twice just swap the map and filter operations to filter entries having null keys:

```
Stream.of(callLegData)
      .map(cld -> new SimpleEntry<>(deviceInfo.buildProperty(cld.key), cld.value))
      .filter(entry -> entry.getKey() != null)
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Comment: Thanks Eritrean, but here deviceInfo.buildProperty(cld.key) gets called twice. Is there any alternative?

Comment: @sushil See my edit to filter null values after mapping.